# How to execute a python-developed software with GPU

Tags: gpu, pyinstaller, nvidia

I need execute a software, which developed by python and compiled by "pyinstaller", on NVIDIA GPU.

As the screen-shot shown below, I can successfully execute chrome.exe on the GPU, but not my own software. I have tried to right click and choose to run with Graphic Processer, but it was not displayed on NVIDIA GPU tracker.

Feel kind of strange, need some help.

Thank you very much.

Best
Frank

Chrome.exe was successfully executed on my GPU.
[image]

Executed my own software.
[image]
[image]

Comment: what happens when you try to execute it with GPU? an error? Or it doenst run? Or it runs in CPU?

Comment: Are you using python code developed using PyCUDA (CUDA) or PyOpenCL (OpenCL)?
You cannot just take normal code and compile it in any way such that it will automatically run on GPU.
The part where Chrome runs on GPU mainly means part of compositing etc that happens in browser is accelerated via GPU while most code still running on CPU.

Comment: @Mikel Hi, It does run, but not in GPU. >.<

Comment: @AquaAsh Hi, I used PyCUDA.

Comment: I would suggest using Task Manager, GPU Z to check GPU h/w usage, if the code is running and you are getting correct result then GPU was used. There is no CPU fallback for CUDA code ( unless explicitly coded).